# Looking for a php class for the new Discogs API (v2.0)

Tags: php, discogs-api

Anyone know of any php classes to interact with the new Discogs API (v2.0)?

I found loads of stuff relating to the old API ([this](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/discogs) for example), but nothing for the new one (which no longer requires an API key).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this? Haven't tested it yet but looks ok, so posting here til I get a chance to try it out: https://github.com/ricbra/php-discogs-api